# $\{Y_i, \forall i \ge 0\}$ is iid random variable, is this equation true?

Tags: probability, independence

$\{Y_i, \forall i \ge 0\}$ is iid random variable, is this equation true
$$  
p(g(Y_{n+1}) = k_{n+1} | f_{n}(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_n) = k_n, f_{n-1}(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_{n-1}) = k_{n-1},...,f_0(Y_0) = k_0) =  p(g(Y_{n+1}) = k_{n+1})
$$
I know $g(Y_{n+1})$ is independent of every $f_i(Y_0, ...,Y_i), \forall i \le n$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $A$ is independent of $B$, then $$p(A\mid B) \equiv \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)} = \frac{p(A) p(B)}{p(B)} = p(A).$$

Comment: I know this defintion,but I still can't figure out how to solve it. Can you provide more detail?